# Mix value from two different rows

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a table in my database for product discount which looks something like this:

```
id  product quantity NewPrice
```

On my website in php at the moment:

for each row:
**Price per unit when buying $quanity or more: $NewPrice**

But what I would like is:

**Price per unit when buying $quanity1-$quanity2: $NewPrice1

Price per unit when buying $quanity2-$quanity3: $NewPrice2

Price per unit when buying $quanity3 or more: $NewPrice3**

So basically I would like to take the quanity-value from two different rows to make up the text for the price from the first row.

If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the results by product, quantity and then loop over the results and compare with the previous row:

```
$lastRow = null;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM prices ORDER BY product, quantity";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($lastRow and $lastRow['product'] == $row['product']) {
        echo "Price per unit when buying ".$lastRow['quantity']." - ".($row['quantity']-1).": ".$lastRow['price']."\n<br>";
    } elseif ($lastRow) {
        echo "Price per unit when buying ".$lastRow['quantity']." or more: ".$lastRow['price']."\n<br>";
    }
    $lastRow = $row;
}
if ($lastRow) {
    echo "Price per unit when buying ".$lastRow['quantity']." or more: ".$lastRow['price']."\n<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get all data from `[discounts table]` by `[product column]` sorted by `[quantity column]`

then extract `[quantity column]` values and work with array

`$quantities = array(quantity0,quantity1,quantity2);

  // $quantities[0] ... $quantities[n]`

- Select from [discounts table] where [product column] = "someid" ORDER BY [quantity column] ASC;
- $quantities = array();
- foreach($row as $r){ $quantities[] = $r[`quantity column name`]; }

you will end up with quantities array, sorted from smallest to biggest
exact procedure depends on your database layer, php framework, and so..